# Wordpress User Name Limitations

Tags: limit, username

I need to know what the wp specifications for the usernames are. Like allowed minimum and maximum length, are special characters like ü,ö,ä,ß accepted,..?

Unfortunately I couldn't find any insight on this in the interweb. Do you have any?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think [the answer is in the source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/formatting.php#L886).

```
$username = wp_strip_all_tags( $username );
$username = remove_accents( $username );
// Kill octets
$username = preg_replace( '|%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])|', '', $username );
$username = preg_replace( '/&.+?;/', '', $username ); // Kill entities

// If strict, reduce to ASCII for max portability.
if ( $strict )
     $username = preg_replace( '|[^a-z0-9 _.\-@]|i', '', $username );
```

So, the code strips tags, octets, and html entities. And it replaces accented characters with unaccented ones via the [`remove_accents`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/formatting.php#L607) function, which is fairly lengthy.  Other characters get through unless `$strict` is `true` (default is `false`), in which case only ASCII characters are allowed.

The maximum login name length would be the [database limit for the user_login column](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table%3a_wp_users)-- 60 characters. The minimum, as best I can tell, is 1.

Comment: thank you! But I think the minimum is 4, at least according to this related question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59760/changing-the-username-character-limit-from-four-to-less-characters?rq=1

Comment: I tested on a dev install and was able to register a user named "y".

Comment: Yeah you are right, I just tested it myself. Strange thing..

Comment: The other question is about multisite. There may be a minimum with that.

Comment: In 2016 I still confirm what @s_ha_dum said: everyone can use an username formed by only 1 character.