# how can I disallow special characters, space, capital letter, dot in user name on registration?

Tags: php

i am running membership site. any one can registered on my site.

i want to disallow special characters(ie:!@#$%^&*), space, capital letter, dot(.) in user name on registration.

i don't have any code that can cover all my (special characters, space, capital letter, dot) requirement. i am using separate separate function to stop this.

### For Capital Latter Disallow In Usernames :

```
add_filter( 'sanitize_user', 'wpse_83689_lower_case_user_name' );
function wpse_83689_lower_case_user_name( $name ) {
if ( function_exists( 'mb_strtolower' ) )
    return mb_strtolower( $name );

return strtolower( $name );
```

### For Spaces Disallow In Usernames :

```
add_filter('validate_username' , 'custom_validate_username', 10, 2);

function custom_validate_username($valid, $username ) {
    if (preg_match("/\\s/", $username)) {
        // there are spaces
        return $valid=false;
    }

return $valid;
}
```

i did lots of google but i did not find any solution for disallow Dot and Special Character.

can any one solve my this problem and combine all 4 option in single function?

sorry for my bad english.

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wordpress User Name Limitations](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/99475/wordpress-user-name-limitations)

Comment: thanks but sorry to say i don't understand that function.

Answer (score 0):

**please try below function for disallow special characters, space, capital letter, dot in user name on registration**

```
 //add a filter to invalidate a username with spaces,special characters, capital letter, dot
    add_filter('validate_username','restrict_space_in_username',10,2);
    function restrict_space_in_username($valid,$user_name){
     //check if there is an space
     if ( preg_match('/\s[!@#$%^&*()+=\-\[\]\';,.\/{}|":<>?~\\\\][A-Z](.)/',$user_name) )
     return false;//if myes, then we say it is an error
     return $valid;//otherwise return the actual validity
    }
```

Comment: thanks for replying, i tried this code but sorry to say its not working, still i am able to create user id with special characters, space, capital letter, dot.

can you check once again from your end please ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression that matches everything **except** lowercase ASCII characters. You can easily add more characters you deem allowable (maybe underscores `_`?) or even some regex magic:

```
add_filter('validate_username', function (bool $isValid, string $username): bool {
    if (preg_match('/[^a-z]/', $username)) {
        return false;
    }
    
    return $isValid;
});
```

The [`validate_user` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/validate_username/) is checked inside [`register_new_user`](https://build.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/5.4/wp-includes/user.php#L2502) and prevents the user from registering if `false` is returned while showing the user an error message.